# Count mismatch in sql browser and java JDBC, due to high transaction

Tags: jakarta-ee, sql-server-2005, transactions

I'm using SQL Server 2005. There is more concurrent access on this **table1**.

When I execute the following query in SQL Browser I'm getting 2000 records, but when the same query is executed with java, no of records r varied.

```
EX: 1st execution --> 2000 records,
    2nd execution --> 2005 records, 
    3rd execution --> 1990 records


 select 
     REGISTRATION_NO as TOTAL_ASSETS_COUNT 
 from 
     Contable1 a 
 inner join 
     table2 b on a.REGISTRATION_NO = b.Registration_no 
              and a.System_id = b.System_id 
 inner join 
     table3 c on b.Registration_no = c.VehicleNo 
              and b.System_id = c.System_id 
 where 
     a.CLIENTID = ? and a.System_id = ? and b.User_id=?
```

I'm using isolation level as **READ COMMITTED**.

Due to high transaction on **table1** the count is varied.

Please help to resolve why the count is varied in java.

NOTE: `Registration_No` is the primary key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say `Due to high transaction on table1 the count is varied.`. Doesn't this answer your next question `please help to resolve why the count is varied in java.`?

Comment: @geert3 thanks for ur response.. what is the root cause for this to happen or wat is limitation on concurrent access on a table

Comment: I am assuming each record count is accurate at the moment it is calculated, and that it's normal to vary over time. In view of the high number of transactions it is likely to be different at any given time. Why is this a problem?

Comment: @geert3.. really happy with your response. even if there is high transaction, those are only update statement not insert statements, and each time i will get only duplicate records which varies the count..

Comment: Updates can very well change the row count for select/join queries. E.g. situation 1: table A has record with ID "X", table B has no such record --> not in resultset. situation 2: update in existing row of B to id "X" --> combination of A/B with ID "X" will be in resultset. You need to be certain that nowhere are you altering joined column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said due to high transaction, there is variation in count.

There may be following possibilities which varies count:

1) There may be some transactions happening in the background before you read the data. or

2) There may be some duplicate data in table you join.

3) As **@greet** said there may be change in values of other table where you join with.

As i would request you to check the queries properly. if you claim that above are not the possibilities. i request you to provide more details about table schema.

Comment: thanks for your response.. i ll chk the above and get back to you